# Rounding up the value to the nearest hour

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime

This is my first time to post a question here, if I don't explain the question very clearly, please give me a chance to improve the way of asking. Thank you!

I have a dataset contains dates and times like this

```
TIME                  COL1         COL2         COL3 ...
2018/12/31 23:50:23    34           DC           23
2018/12/31 23:50:23    32           NC           23
2018/12/31 23:50:19    12           AL           33
2018/12/31 23:50:19    56           CA           23
2018/12/31 23:50:19    98           CA           33
```

I want to create a new column and the format would be like '2018-12-31 11:00:00 PM' instead of '2018/12/31 23:10:23' and 17:40 was rounded up to 6:00

I have tried to use `.dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")` to change the format and then when I try to convert the time from 12h to 24h, I stuck here.

```
Name: TIME, Length: 3195450, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

I found out the type of `df['TIME']` is `pandas.core.series.Series`

Now I have no idea about how to continue. Please give me some ideas, hints or any instructions. Thank you very much!

Comment: Any column extraction like that is a series.  You need the type of the column cells.  Look up how to do that.  They should be `datetime` objects.  If not, convert them.  Then look up how to manipulate `datetime` values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your example it seems you want to floor to the hour, instead of round? In any case, first make sure your TIME column is of [datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) dtype.

```
df['TIME'] = pd.to_datetime(df['TIME'])
```

Now floor (or round) using the [dt accessor](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.html) and an [offset alias](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#offset-aliases):

```
df['newTIME'] = df['TIME'].dt.floor('H') # could use round instead of floor here

# df['newTIME'] 
# 0   2018-12-31 23:00:00
# 1   2018-12-31 23:00:00
# 2   2018-12-31 23:00:00
# 3   2018-12-31 23:00:00
# 4   2018-12-31 23:00:00
# Name: newTIME, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Afer that, you can format to string in a desired format, again using the `dt` accessor to access properties of a datetime series:

```
df['timestring'] = df['newTIME'].dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S %p")

# df['timestring']
# 0    2018-12-31 11:00:00 PM
# 1    2018-12-31 11:00:00 PM
# 2    2018-12-31 11:00:00 PM
# 3    2018-12-31 11:00:00 PM
# 4    2018-12-31 11:00:00 PM
# Name: timestring, dtype: object
```

Comment: Very appreciate!